# Regex not working for multiple pattern occurence

Tags: python, regex

I want to grab every first occurence of strings which is followed by `"genome_"` but ending before `",("` and replace it with a particular string, say `"XXX"`

In the text below:

> (ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C182_genome_orf00003____Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._843_unknown___1278-2120_1_^^**neighbours_ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C182_genome_orf00002_1__ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C182_genome_orf00004_1__neighbour_genes_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-..**:0.00000230914009336068,((ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-G421_genome_orf00003____Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._843_unknown___1315-2157_1_^^**neighbours_ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-G421_genome_orf00002_1__ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-G421_genome_orf00004_1__neighbour_genes_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-..**:0.00000230914009336068,ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C339_genome_orf00003____Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._843_unknown___1084-1926_1_^^**neighbours_ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C339_genome_orf00002_1__ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C339_genome_orf00004_1__neighbour_genes_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-.._Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-..**:0.00000230914009336068)28:0.00000230914009336068,(

desired result:

> (ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C182_XXX,((ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-G421_XXX,(

Comment: desired result:

(ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-C182_XXX,((ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-G421_XXX,(

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using (PCRE, python), javascript)?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am using Python's re module. have tried a few patterns: '_genome_.*\,\('   and   '_genome_.*?\,\('

Comment: If you *have tried a few patterns*, certainly you have at least a *few patterns* that you can include in your post to show what you've tried.

Comment: Just edited my comment with the pattern that i tried.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data and desired output, positive look-around should help:

```
(?<=ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-[A-Z]\d{3,3}_)(genome.*?)(?=,\()
```

- `(?<=ID_Bxylanisolvens_NLAE-zl-[A-Z]\d{3,3}_)` looks back and checks for that particular sequence of characters. Might need adjustment depending on the actual data's variability.
- `(genome.*?)` catches the bit to replace - with the question mark making it non-greedy.
- `(?=,\()` looking forward for the character combination to delimit the to be dropped portion.

See it in action: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/bJ2rJ1/1).
Please comment if and as further detail / adjustment is required.